# Использование создаваемой колонки в Generated column

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Мне нужно при помощи If else вычислить значение создаваемой через Generated column колонки, но тк я эту колонку создаю и при ее создании вычисление провожу с ней же, выдает ошибку `"generated column can refer only to generated columns defined prior to it"`

Вот пример кода:

```
CREATE TABLE `Slicer` (
  `id` int NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Polimer_consumption_ml` FLOAT  NULL,
  `Side_consumption_ml` FLOAT GENERATED ALWAYS AS 
  (CASE WHEN `Polimer_consumption_ml`<4 THEN `Side_consumption_ml` = `Polimer_consumption_ml` * 0.7 
  ELSE `Side_consumption_ml` = `Polimer_consumption_ml` * 0.2 END) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`));
```

Помогите пожалуйста, что делать, как использовать создаваемую колонку в этом же Generated column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
CREATE TABLE `Slicer` (
    `id` int NOT NULL,
    `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `Polimer_consumption_ml` FLOAT NULL,
    `Side_consumption_ml` FLOAT GENERATED ALWAYS AS 
        (CASE WHEN `Polimer_consumption_ml` < 4 
              THEN `Polimer_consumption_ml` * 0.7 
              ELSE `Polimer_consumption_ml` * 0.2 
              END) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```